# Why does STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE turn on by itself?

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, clustered-index, indexed-view

I am running SQL Server 13.0.5622.0. I have a number of large indexed views (>5MM rows) defined similar to:

```
CREATE VIEW MyView WITH SCHEMABINDING AS
  SELECT T1.Column1, T1.Column2
  FROM dbo.T1
  INNER JOIN dbo.T2 ON T2.Id = T1.Id
  WHERE T2.Column3 IS NULL
GO

CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX IX_MyView ON MyView
(
  Column1 ASC,
  Column2 ASC
) 
WITH (DATA_COMPRESSION = PAGE)
ON Primary
GO
```

After I create the view & index, everything is fine. When I come back a few hours later, I run the following code (from [How do I find indexes that have statistics_norecompute = ON](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55993851/85196))

```
SELECT 
  OBJECT_NAME(i.object_id) AS table_name,
  i.name AS index_name,
  s.name
FROM sys.indexes AS i
LEFT JOIN sys.stats AS s ON
  i.index_id = s.stats_id
  AND i.object_id = s.object_id
WHERE s.no_recompute = 1
```

and notice that, for some reason, the index now has `STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = ON`. I edit the index options, set `STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF`, and then several hours later when I check again, `STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE` is back `ON` again. I'm unable to find documentation saying that SQL Server will automatically set `STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = ON` or under what conditions it does so. Does anybody know why this is happening? Will query efficiency suffer with `STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = ON`? Should I set up a background job to update statistics on these indexes manually at set times?

Comment: "notice", "check again" - where? (I ask because scripting options might override the current state.)

Comment: @AaronBertrand I've added the query and a link to the source above.

Comment: Also maybe it's just a dumbed-down example but why is this an indexed view? What does the indexed view solve that couldn't be solved with indexes on T1/T2? What else has happened in those few hours? Maintenance like index rebuilds, defrag, stats updates?

Comment: @AaronBertrand I am joining and filtering information from several tables and indexing the result so I can query it without needing to denormalize the data every time the query runs.

Comment: The right indexes can often do that for you. The main sweet spot for indexed views is when you are reducing the amount of data you need to read by pre-calculating aggregates and drastically collapsing row count. This is a separate issue from your question but I'd love to see an example where an indexed view helps this process and I can't suggest non-clustered indexes that would do it just as well or better.

Comment: @AaronBertrand For most cases I would agree with you, but this query is critical to performance for a large-scale OLTP application, must execute extremely fast, and runs several times per second. Plus there's a lot more joining and filtering going on than what I'm showing in the simplified example above.

Comment: Ok, I'll take your word for it, but I have been using SQL Server since 6.5 and I have yet to see a single case where an indexed view improved performance of a _non-aggregation_ join query better than indexes on the joined tables. And often the impact to the write portion of the workload means you're worse off overall. If you _think_ the indexed views are faster than indexes on the base tables that help the query, you should confirm. /shrug